# execute mysql commands via desktop shortcut?

Tags: mysql, automation, command

On a windows machine, every day i have to login to **mysql** via phpmyadmin, go to a particular table and run the same sql command to do some cleanup.

I want to automate this process without setting up a TRIGGER.....is there a command prompt solution for doing this, or an automatic process that can be simply run from a desktop shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Write a script Run.bat and copy the following contents in it:

mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -D database_name -e "cleanup command".

Schedule this command in your windows scheduler.

If you have multiple cleanup commands, then add them in a sql file and then schedule the following command:

mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -D database_name < path_to_sql_file

Answer (score 0):

For windows you could use the task scheduler. You might not be able to get it to login to phpMyAdmin though. Perhaps cmd line for mysql?